# Secure sensitive Android strings

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-functions

I have some sensitive strings I'd like to secure. For example:

- My Admob ID
- My Mapbox private key

It appears that the Admob ID has to be in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <!-- AdMob -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/admob_app_id"/>
```

Is there any way to secure this ID so reverse engineers can't access it?

I load my Mapbox private key in my Fragment:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val ac = activity?.applicationContext ?: return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false)
    Mapbox.getInstance(ac, resources.getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token))
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false)
}
```

Is there anyway to secure this as well? I implement [cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) which has a secure node.js server - but the above APIs are native Android.

Any idea?

Comment: Anything that you allow to exist on a client device is no longer truly private. If you encrypt data, you must also provide the algo and data to decrypt in order to make use of it, and that all can be reverse engineered.  All you can do is make that more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Any information existing in the APP can be decompiled. All you can do is add encryption and decryption algorithms to make it difficult for the APP to be easily broken. At the same time, the signature verification of the so library can be done to strengthen the security of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should check this for hiding completely all resources (strings included): [AndResGuard](https://github.com/shwenzhang/AndResGuard)